# Why do developers write these type of scripts for embedding when a simple tag would do?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just wanted to ask a question about a practice I have seen quite a lot recently regarding jQuery/Javascript plugins/widgets written by other developers.

I maintain a number of sites and I am usually asked to add new scripts for various things such as chat widgets, marketing tools etc etc however the code I am usually sent for the majority of these looks is something like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

(function() {

var hm = document.createElement('script'); hm.type ='text/javascript';     hm.async = true;

hm.src = ('++www-widget-org+widget-js').replace(/[+]/g,'/').replace(/-/g,'.');

var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];     s.parentNode.insertBefore(hm, s);

})();

</script>
```

Now my question is why go to all the trouble of writing the above script when all you really need to do is this?

```
<script src="//www.widget.org/widget.js" type="text/javascript" async></script>
```

I have seen this a number of times and I am beginning to wonder what the benefit of this approach actually is? If there is one?

Comment: Generally, a lot of them also add additional information (like user agent, screen size, etc.) This provides a great opportunity to pass this info off to the vendor in the form of query string parameters appended to the asset. GoogleAnalytics also establishes values such as the GA account reference before the remote resource is loaded.

Comment: I think putting small scripts into the html file makes the code more compact and easier to edit than having two or three files... but I'm no fan of doing this, too

Comment: it does, as written ensure it gets inserted before the other scripts.

Comment: You can avoid additional http calls if you don't load multiple js files. These can really add up if you use more than one widget/plugin.

Comment: Not sure if there is a reason but it would load on the document ready event rather than during the page load - and asynchronous so it might be some analytic thing or similar - but I am just regurgitating thoughts really without seeing the loaded script.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss: The order isn't the big concern so much as it's one of the most reliable (present) elements on the page. Some interesting reading: http://www.jspatterns.com/the-ridiculous-case-of-adding-a-script-element/

Comment: mostly to load extra libraries asynchronously (and not block the browser) plus to add extra info (sometimes, depending on script) like user-agent, etc..

Comment: most google APIs do that, they load the dependencies dynamicaly, by adding `<script>` tag dynamicaly

Comment: @BradChristie - yes, and I have done that myself given that context, for that reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Steve Souders](http://stevesouders.com/about.php), this method is used to [load scripts in a non-blocking fashion](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/04/27/loading-scripts-without-blocking/). This makes sense given these scripts are generally supplemental to the page and not directly related to function (why make your site slow just because you added Google Analytics, etc.).

There's other scripts that use this opportunity to initialize some very basic data (e.g. GoogleAnalytics uses this to `_setAccount`). I've also seen scripts aggregate user statistics (screen size, agent, and other client data) and pass them off to the remote script as well (in query parameters they can later review/analyze to gain detail about their demographic).